# UTF-8 fonts in maven-pdf-plugin

Tags: maven, pdf, apache-fop, maven-pdf-plugin

Is there any way to attach custom fonts to Maven proejct that has documentation generated with `maven-pdf-plugin`? My project has a documentation written in **LaTeX** and I wanted to integrate with with Maven build. The problem is that I see completely no way to attach custom fonts, as the default ones contain only ANSI characters.

Or maybe there is some other plugin that is capable of processing Maven site sources and dumping them into PDF?

Comment: This might something you are interested in: http://mojo.codehaus.org/latex-maven-plugin/

Comment: Thanks for your reploy - yes, I use it for my LaTeX documentation to generate it as PDF, but I would like to use same sources to build PDF version and on-line site documentation.

Answer (score 0):

As the maven-plugin mentions by khmarbaise is not available anymore you could use a different one. There is a new maven-plugin which comes with none or less configuration to get the latex build integrated in maven.

Have a look at [mathan-latex-maven-plugin](https://github.com/reallyinsane/mathan-latex-maven-plugin)